# console.readline display something before

Tags: c#, console.readline

I have something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Y =");
Y = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

and it displays like this

```
Y=
//and here i have to input my value
```

I want to put my value on the same row

```
Y= //here to input my value
```

Any tips?

Comment: Maybe `Console.Write("Y =");`

Comment: or add a space after the equals `"Y = "`

Comment: Yep... i am real new to C#, in C was far more easy. 10x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Then you neeed

```
Console.Write("Y = ");
```

instead of

```
Console.WriteLine("Y = ");
```

Answer (score 2):

try `Console.Write("Y =");`

instead of

```
Console.WriteLine("Y = ");
```

because writeline provides new line while only Write does not.

As documented here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5ff3931a-8113-4f8c-a1dd-801d8e6db0e5/whats-the-difference-between-write-and-writeline :-

> Write procedure writes a text and places the caret to after the last
>   character in the text.
>
> **Console.Write("Thank you")** -
>
> **Output**: Thank you)
>
> WriteLine rocedure writes a text and places the caret to the next
>   line(like pressing enter in MS WORD)
>
> **Console.WriteLine("Thank you")** -
>
> **Output**: Thank you
>
> | -> caret is placed here.
>
> )
>
> Environment.NewLine forces the caret to to a new line.(like \n in
>   programming languages)
>
> **Console.Write("Thank" + Environment.NewLine + "you")** -
>
> **Output**: Thank
>
> you)